# How to run a unit test on an existing project with main function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to add a google-unit-test to my existing c++ project

I added an google-unit-test project to my solution. So now in my solution I have a google-unit-test project with a main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

And in my existing project I have a main as well.
The build works fine:
[image: build succeeded]

But when I execute the code only the project's main is running and I don't know how to run the test's main. I don't want to run the test every time I run the project but I don't know how to run the test at all.

Comment: Each executable has its own main function. You need to run the *test* executable.

Comment: @StoryTeller is there an option the run the executable from visual studio?. If I run the exe file it gets closed right away and not given me the info in a nice UI like that: https://youtu.be/16FI1-d2P4E?t=342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the test executable file. You can run it by opening the executable in Command Prompt. 
If you need a UI, there is a visual studio extension called ReSharper.